# what kind of mobile will be updated to Android 4.0.3 or 4.1 version?

Tags: android, android-layout, mobile, android-emulator, screen

I made an application under Android emulator provided worked perfectly on all types of dispositives (small, normal, large, xlarge) (-ldpi,-mdpi, -hdpi,-xhdpi). But the last few days I saw that in some phones with the latest versions of android (these phones consist with a lower bar like tablets) did not look properly.

So my question is: what kind of phones have or can upgrade to these versions of android? (small-HDPI, normal-HDPI, normal-xhdpi???)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, nothing stops a manufacturer from making an ldpi device capable of running ICS or JB. However, in practice, most devices with ldpi and even mdpi to some extent do not have good enough processors in both CPU and GPU departments to be able to run the newer version of Android.

Till date, the lowest I've seen an ICS device go screenwise is a normal-mdpi display. However, I do not know the details of every device in existence, and there could be lower devices as well.

You should design your app keeping in mind all device configs, at most excluding only ldpi and small displays.

Comment: You'll want to open a new question for that, as it is very different from what you originally asked.